# Team goes from place to place via doors with key pads

Tags: story-identification, tv, soft-sci-fi

I'm looking for a kids' sci-fi TV show.

What I remember is a team would go from place to place via doors with key pads.  There was also a round floor disc that would transport people down a long corridor.

The people at each door/world they would visit didn't seem to know anything outside of their own place.  It was not Starlost.

Comment: Scifi or scifi/educational?

Comment: When did you see it? How old was it? Where was it made? *Any* extra detail you can remember might help someone to identify it! See also [our](http://meta.scifi.stackexchange.com/a/9337/31394) [guidance](http://meta.scifi.stackexchange.com/a/9336/31394) on asking good story-ID questions.

Comment: You say it's not Starlost, but you're basically describing Starlost, except with kids.

Comment: @Valorum The OP doesn't even say it's _with_ kids, just that it's a kids' show.